# How do I change the .prose class to .Normal in Tailwind CSS Typography plugin?

Tags: tailwind-css

I have Tailwind 2.2.6 and the official Tailwind Typography plugin installed on a relatively vanilla setup. I'm building a website on a CMS which uses the CSS class ".Normal" for all typography.

How do I change the Tailwind typography class from .prose to .Normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robin from TailwindCSS answered this for me

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    // ...
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography')({ className: 'Normal' }),
    // ...
  ],
}
```